# 最終講義・懇親会の出欠連絡の葉書に、伝統的にどんなコメントを書くべきですか。

Tags: expressions

去年の3月まで所属していた大学講座から、「最終講義・懇親会」の案内が来ました。

欠席・出席を返答する葉書が入っていました。一番下のところに、「コメント欄」があります。そこに、「特に行けない人は、コメントを書いて欲しい」というようなことが書いてありました。

私が行ける場合は、その欄には何も書かないで送るのが普通ですか。あるいは、伝統的に何か書いた方がいいですか。何か書いたほうがよい場合、普通何を書きますか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

出席できる場合は、以下のようなメッセージを添えた方が丁寧だと思います。

> ご招待ありがとうございます。当日お会いできることを楽しみにしております。

欠席の場合は、

> ご招待ありがとうございます。昨年は大変お世話になりました。当日はあいにく都合が付かず欠席とさせて頂きます。今後もますますのご活躍をお祈りいたします。

などはいかがでしょう（スペースに応じて適当に省略してください）。

「退職　あいさつ　文例」などで検索すると色々出ます。

- [退職 挨拶 メール 返信 文例](http://uluss.com/outlookshare/taisyoku-aisatu-mail-bunrei/)
- [どう返す？退職の挨拶メールに対する適切な返信定型文まとめ](http://careerpark.jp/4110?page=2)

まあ、大学教授なら英語で書いても全く問題ないとは思いますが…。

Comment: 最後のことはnarutoさんがあまり大学に入っていないと思います。旧帝大また有名私立大を除く英語できる先生は１、２割です。

Answer (score 5):

> 行ける場合は、その欄には何も書かないで送るのが普通ですか。

何も書かない人もたくさんいます。
「御出席」の「御」を二重線で消して、その下に「させて頂きます」と付け加えるだけの人もいます。

> あるいは、伝統的に何か書いた方がいいですか。何か書いたほうがよい場合、普通何を書きますか。

特に決まっていないと思いますが、もし書くとすれば、

> (この[度]{たび}は)ご[退官]{たいかん}おめでとうございます。
>   (是非とも)[拝聴]{はいちょう}させていただきます。

といったことを書くとよいかと思います。
欠席する場合は、行けないということを詫びる文とともに

> ご[退官]{たいかん}おめでとうございます。
>   在学中は大変お世話になりました。（←その教授があなたの恩師である場合）
>   今後とも引き続きご[指導]{しどう}ご[鞭撻]{べんたつ}(orご[教示]{きょうじ}ご鞭撻) を[賜]{たまわ}りますよう(orの[程]{ほど}、) お願い申し上げます。 （←特にあなたが研究者の場合）
>   今後の[益々]{ますます}のご[活躍]{かつやく}とご[健勝]{けんしょう}を[祈念]{きねん}いたします。

といったことを書くとよいかと思います。